# Regular template

Tags: org-mode

On a near weekly basis, I need to create an org entry that looks something like

```
* <TODAYS DATE>
  - <Person 1>
    - What this person did
  - <Person 2>
    - What this person did
  - <Person 3>
    - What this person did
  - <Person 4>
    - What this person did
```

Is there an idiomatic way to generate this structure with org-mode? My naive idea would be to just define a function in my `init.el` that does

```
(defun some-useful-function-name ()
    (insert "* <TODAYS DATE>
  - Person 1
    - FILL ME IN
  - Person 2
    - FILL ME IN
  - Person 3
    - FILL ME IN
  - Person 4
    - FILL ME IN"))
```

Comment: Are the items `Person 1` to `Person 4` given in form of names in a list? Are the items `What this person did` variable? Note, AFAIK the current org approach for that stuff is to use [`tempo` templates](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TempoMode).

Comment: @Tobias, I'll update the question to make that clearer. Person 1 - 4 are a list of values, `What this person did` will be something that I actually need to fill in manually

Comment: You can define a [capture template](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html#Capture) for this. In particular, you can use `%^{PROMPT}` to prompt you for the work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for NickD for pointing me towards the capture templates!

I've now set up a capture template that does this. The custom-set-variables call looks something like:

```
'(org-capture-templates
   (quote
    (("B" "Weekly report" entry
      (file "~/org/file-to-store-it-in.org")
      "* %u
- Person 1
    -%^{PROMPT}
- Person 2
    -%^{PROMPT}
- Person 3
    -%^{PROMPT}
- Person 4
    -%^{PROMPT}"))))
```